# It is possible to generate DDL using Hibernate + Maven during build time?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, maven

My goal is to get DDL generation during build time and save it in specific place with specific name.

Also it's important to have it on declarative level. Without writing java code.

Comment: It probably is. But it's hard to say without knowing your projects details, what kind of dll you want to build? What is your current project configuration? Please provide details.

Comment: @PierreB.it should be simple DDL like hibernate generates in console output on "create" config. Project config.. if I understood your question right its spring based web app with liquibase and maven as build tool.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as follow. Assuming you are using hibernate 5+. You can use [hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin](http://jpdigital.github.io/hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>de.jpdigital</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin-hibernate52</artifactId> <!-- Change to match your Hibernate version -->
        <version>2.0.0</version> <!-- Change to latest version available -->
        <configuration>
            <dialects>
                <param>postgresql9</param>
            </dialects>
            <customDialects> <!-- Optional -->
                <param>org.example.dialects.FooDBDialect</param>
            </customDialects>
            <packages>
                <param>org.example.entities</param>
            </packages>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>gen-ddl</goal>
                </goals>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```